# Xamarin.Forms DateTime.Now() date does not match current date

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a user that keeps getting an error where his DateTime.Now() timestamp is a day or two behind the current system DateTime. This application is working correctly on ~80 other devices.

Restarting the application seems to correct the issue. Does anyone have any experience with this issue?

I am accessing the System.DateTime from a static helper class, here are the variables that get the current date and time:

```
    public static string DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss";
    public static string ShortDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm";
    public static string DateOnlyFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    public static string Today = DateTime.Now.ToString(DateFormat);
    public static string TodayDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(DateOnlyFormat);
    public static string CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
```

Comment: Could it be that the application does not restart and the "Today" datime never gets updated? I mean it will only get a value the first time, and then it will not update. If that's the case you may want to use something like `public static string TodayDate {get => DateTime.Now....}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fields(!)

```cs
public static string Today = DateTime.Now.ToString(DateFormat);
```

are initialized *exactly once*, when the program starts or the class where this definition is is first used.

You likely want to use a property instead:

```cs
public static string Today => DateTime.Now.ToString(DateFormat);
```

This returns a new string each time it is requested.

Comment: Thank you, I will mark this as the answer, for now. I thought it may be something like this.

Comment: And if you want the current *time* to display the correct value (or the date to be correct past midnight) then you will need some timer to continuously (once a minute may be enough) update the display of that time (and/or date)

Comment: Thanks Hans, luckily this is more of a timestamp during business hours.